# How to avoid/rectify pinching

Tags: subdivision-surface

How do I avoid and/or rectify the pinching, that is quite visible even with a subdivision-surface modifier active, that seems to be the result of one extra edge joining at a vertex?

I tried shrink wrapping it, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here you could remove the edge loops in order to remove the triangles

Comment: @moonboots could you elaborate on your comment? I don't understand what you exactly mean by it.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the triangles that create these bad pinching, select the edge ring with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Al</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>:

[image]

Then <kbd>X</kbd> > Collapse Edges & Faces:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: But that would reduce the 'resolution' on the model? I added those extra edges because they are needed there?

Comment: I'm not sure that they are needed, even if you need a high resolution mesh, apply a Subdivision Surface modifier?